# Play audio when it is loaded in HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a simple HTML5 audio tag on my page. How can I automatically play audio file, when it just will be loaded? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I appreciate your requirement, but I'm compelled to advise: if at all possible _don't do it!_

Comment: Autoplay doesn't work on some platforms, like the iPhone. And also, welcome back to embedded MIDI files of 1997! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the autoplay attribute to "autoplay":

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

But since autoplay is a boolean attribute you can just set it

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple way is to put "autoplay" attribute into your "audio" tag.
Or you can use some .play() function on the element when the DOM will be ready (or the audio will be preloaded).

Comment: And yes, you really should not do this.